# Multiple Second Level Cache Settings With One Hibernate Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, second-level-cache

Supose that there multiple Java applications which share a **common** entity module (Entity classes + Hibernate XML mappings). Currently, the entities are not enabled for caching (no `<cache.../>` elements within the mappings).

Most of the applications are largly concerned with editing single entities an thus it cannot relie on second level cache.

Now, a new application is implemented which

1. Should use the same entity mappings
2. but must use 2nd level and query cache.

**How to configure the cache?**

Several observations:

1. I cannot add `<cache.../>` elements to the mappings since this would break the other applications which do not configure such a cache and which are not under my influence:

   `Second-level cache is not enabled for usage [hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache | hibernate.cache.use_query_cache]`
2. I can't find a way to activate an entity for caching outside of its mapping. Setting up a cache region for an entity in `ehcache.xml` does not help
3. Even if I could change all the other applications and add `<cache.../>` to the entity mappings, it does not work to disable the cache by setting `hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false` although it is said so in http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html, table 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can use `<class-cache>` elements to configure caching in `hibernate.cfg.xml` rather than in entity mappings, see [3.8. XML configuration file](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-xmlconfig).

I guess you can afford creating a custom `hibernate.cfg.xml` that would use existing mappings, and if not, there are `Configuration.setCacheConcurrencyStrategy()` methods that might help as well.

Comment: Thank you, must have been blind, but I really tried to find such a configuration option. 

For those who like programmatic Spring configuration using e.g. a `LocalSessionFactoryBean`, the corresponsing method is `setEntityCacheStrategies(Properties entityCacheStrategies)`

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setEntityCacheStrategies(java.util.Properties)